# Configure BRAT so that if no `.ann` file is found, then an empty `.ann` file is created

Tags: nlp

I am annotating a new corpus with BRAT. I have a set of `.txt` files to annotate. Is it possible to configure BRAT so that if no `.ann` file is found, then an empty `.ann` file is created? Or am I supposed to myself provide the empty `.ann` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into the same problem with BRAT from time to time. The way I solved it for a folder with `.txt` files is to run this Bash one-liner directly in the shell when inside the directory with these files:

```
for f in *.txt; do touch $(basename $f .txt)".ann"; done
```

What is does is the following: With a for-loop, it loops over every `.txt` file, and creates an empty file with `touch` having the same basename, but a `.ann` extension instead of a `.txt` extension.